# XSL: Test if there is only one child node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have some XML-Code that looks like:

```
<l>
    some text <app><rdg>text inside an app</rdg></app>
</l>
<l>
    <app><rdg>line with text inside an app</rdg></app>
</l>
```

I want to process the XML with XSLT and append different attributes to the output, depending on:

1. If the line contains text and an `<app>` and an `<rdg>`with text in it
2. If line contains only text, that is inside an `<rdg>`-Element

I tried the following solution, which does not work for me:

```
<xsl:for-each select="l">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="app/rdg">
                <myElement>
                    <xsl:attribute name="class" select="'case1'"/>
                </myElement>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when
                test="app/rdg[not(../following-sibling::*) and 
    not(../preceding-sibling::*)]">
                <myElement>
                    <xsl:attribute name="class" select="'case2'"/>
                </myElement>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Is there a way to distinguish these two (or of course even more) cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first condition

> *If the line contains text and an* `<app>` *and an* `<rdg>` *with text in it*

It is equal to this XPath expression:

```
text() and app[rdg]
```

Your second condition

> *If line contains only text, that is inside an* `<rdg>`*-Element*

It's equal to this XPath expression:

```
not(.//text()[not(parent::rdg)])
```

All these in the context of an `l` element.

Comment: Thanks – although the second expression did not work for me (maybe my explanation was too short) a fine solution. For the second condition it's just this simple like `not(text())`.

Comment: `not(text())` should be read as _"not having a text node child"_. It has nothing about an `rdg` element parent.